# How much faster are Form I-485 forms processed when the applicant requested expedited processing through the USCIS Contact Center?

Tags: usa, paperwork, us-residents

I read on https://www.boundless.com/immigration-resources/form-i-485-explained/:

> Premium processing is not available for Form I-485, but you may be able to request expedited processing through the [USCIS Contact Center](https://www.uscis.gov/contactcenter). Make sure to have your 13-digit USCIS Form I-485 [receipt number](https://www.boundless.com/immigration-resources/how-to-check-green-card-status/#receipt-numbers) on hand so that your request can be forwarded to the correct office.

How much faster are Form I-485 forms processed when the applicant requested expedited processing through the USCIS Contact Center?

Comment: One would assume it depends on the reasons, the field office involved, and whatever case-load the assigned officer has. Voting to close as unanswerable.

Comment: @littleadv Some statistics might help with setting some overall expectations and planning ahead.

Comment: What basis would one have for expediting I-485? Since an I-485 applicant is allowed to stay in the US without time limit while I-485 is pending, what hardship does I-485 being slow cause?